# Calculating the probability of committing a type I error

Tags: probability

I've never calculated the probability of type I errors before, and just wanted to verify that this is indeed correct:

Question:

A manufacturer has developed a new fishing line, which the company claims has a mean breaking strength of $15$ kilograms with a standard deviation of $0.5$ kilogram. To test the hypothesis that $H_0 : \mu = 15$ kilograms against the alternative that $H_1 : \mu < 15$ kilograms, a random sample of $50$ lines will be tested. The critical region is defined to be $\bar{x} < 14.9$.
Find the probability of committing a type I error when $H_0$ is true.

My answer:

$$z = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{14.9 - 15}{\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{50}}} = -\sqrt{2}$$

Thus the probability of committing a type I error is:

$$\mathbb{P}\{Z \leq z\} = \mathbb{P}\{Z \leq -\sqrt{2}\}$$

which is then calculated with the tables for normal distribution. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Looks fine. The tricky thing in these kind of problems is usually figuring out what the rejection region should be but here it was just given. (Just a warning in advance: in realistic situations, you can't really take the population standard deviation as given and instead need to estimate it from the sample. When you estimate the standard deviation and the underlying population is normal (but unknown standard deviation), you use the Student's t distribution instead of the normal distribution.)